# Как заполнить пустоты в Masonry layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Создал такую разметку

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.grid').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    horizontalOrder: true,
    gutter: 10
    //columnWidth: 200
  });

});
```

```css
.width-1 {
  width: 534px;
  float: left;
}

.width-2 {
  width: 275px;
  float: left;
}

.width-3 {
  width: 265px;
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item width-1"><img src="images/masonry/1portfolio-work-534.png" alt="work"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-1"><img src="images/masonry/2portfolio-work-1-534.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-3"><img src="images/masonry/3portfolio-work-11-265.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-1"><img src="images/masonry/7portfolio-work-8-265.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-2"><img src="images/masonry/4portfolio-work-7-275.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-3"><img src="images/masonry/5portfolio-work-10-265.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-3"><img src="images/masonry/6portfolio-work-9-534.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-3"><img src="images/masonry/8portfolio-work-265.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-3"><img src="images/masonry/9portfolio-work-6-275.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-2"><img src="images/masonry/10portfolio-work1-265.png" alt="port"></div>
  <div class="grid-item width-2"><img src="images/masonry/11portfolio-work-5-275.png" alt="port"></div>
</div>
```

Но у меня вышел какой-то хаос

[image: Подскажите как заполнить свободное пространство]

Comment: а `gutter:10` вам ни очем не говорит?

Comment: без него тоже самое

Comment: а что вы хотели получить?